# normal approximation

Tags: statistics

It is estimated that a jury will reach the correct decision  (guilty or not) 92% of the time in a random sample of 200 trials.

A)What is the probability that the jury will reach the correct decision in at 
 least 175 of the trials.

B) what is the probability that there will be fewer than 180 correct decisions?

C) what is the probability that there will be exactly 184 correct decisions?

So I have different answers every time I do this question.

Values are  n=200,  p=.92, q= .08, mean= 184 SD= 3.836665219

For part A I got 0.0073
For part B I got 0.1492
For part C I got .1034

any help would be great to make sure I am on the correct track.

Please and thank you

Comment: Can you explain your answer to $A$?  it seems absurdly low.  After all the expected number of correct decisions is $.92\times 200=184$ so you expect to get more than $175$ right.

Comment: Also your answers for $A$ and $C$ are inconsistent.

Comment: I agree with your answer for $C$.  For $B$ I get a similar number but not exactly the same.  Are you using an approximation (I doubt it...the answers are too far apart).

Comment: Oh, I see.  You are using a normal approximation but you are getting the continuity correction wrong.  You should integrate up to $179.5$, not up to $180$.

Comment: For A I am using the continuity correction therefore I have for x=174.5 and x=175.5 , solve finding z values = -2.48 and-2.20 which score 0.0139 and 0.0066 (0.0139-.0066= 0.0073)  this doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: Perhaps you are just misreading $A$.  It asks for the probability that you get at least $175$.  So you want to integrate from $174.5$ to $200$.

Comment: It's easy enough to get the answers exactly.  For $A$ I get $0.990062975$.  Using the normal, and $174.5$ I get $0.993358843$

Comment: Ok changed the values on it to 174.5-200 this will give me a z score of -2.48 and  4.17, since the 4.17 is greater than the  3.49 I assume the value of 1, which would be 1-.0066= .9934, so out of 175 trials that would be the probability?

Comment: Yes, that's what I get from the normal approximation.  And for $B$, using $179.5$, I get $0.120419242$ while the binomial distribution gives $0.122456645$ for the exact value.

Comment: Okay just want to make sure we are on the same page for values for A I use 174.5-200,  for B I use 179.5  only and for C I use  183.5-184.5?

Comment: Would I have to add .5 to the 200?

Comment: Well if you just do the standard normal approximation then you already are getting the integral from, $179.5$ to $\infty$.  To be sure, the difference is negligible.  Running the normal distribution just up to $200$ instead of $\infty$ I get $0.999984789$ so ignoring the cutoff really doesn't change things.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** For comparison, here are exact binomial values from
R statistical software, where `pbinom` is the CDF and `dbinom` is the PDF.

```
p = .92; n = 200
1 - pbinom(174, n, p)
## 0.990063       #(a)
pbinom(179, n, p)
## 0.1224566      #(b)
dbinom(184, n, p)
## 0.1034377      #(c)
```

The following graph shows how well the 'best fitting' normal curve (blue) actually fits this
binomial distribution (black bars).

[image]

A correct continuity correction is crucial in (c), and happily this is
a value for which the normal curve very nearly matches the binomial.